# Issues setting units to 0.01 meters

Tags: coordinates, units, system

When I set the scene units to 0.01 meters several issues appear, and I hope there's a simple solution.

- When set to adjust origin, the origin access icon is ridiculously tiny (this would be a nightmare in 0.001m)
- Viewport (and camera) clipping get set to very tiny; 0.0000001-2m
- Creation of bones, empties, etc are tiny
- Ridid body has numerous issues; mass defaults to 0.0001, forces require ridiculous levels (10+ digits), Gravity changes to 0.09981, etc

Does anyone know how to fix all this (and possibly more)?

Comment: You could try keeping the units in 1 but changing the Scene legth to millimiter

Comment: Suggestion by @Emir seems to produce a better result, including a better scaling for new objects.  Not sure why, but perhaps there is some bug in calculating scaling.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work for me, the units have to be 0.01 because our 'pipeline' requires us to go from Blender--> Maya--> Unreal (don't ask  ). If the units in Blender are 1 it comes in to Maya at 100 scale, and that won't do. 